# how to bring Core forum discussion with comment on front page

Tags: views, 7, theming

I am using core forum in drupal 7. my requirement is how to bring forum discussion question with comment on front page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) of type **Forum topic**. and put the views page on your sites front page.

navigate to `[your-site]/admin/config/system/site-information`  change the **default front page** to your views page link.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply and i will try. my requirement is i want to use two content on front page.so how can i achieve this functionality.

Comment: Create the same view as Shrish says but make it as block. The add the block in the homepage via context or Manage Block page.